# Convert Python to Java 8

Tags: java, python, postgis

I’m working in a project that use java 8, this project is about get some geographic information and work with this.
I already have done part of this work in python, and now I’m translating this part did in Python to java 8, well in Python I use this lines bellow to convert coordinates in Google format to Postgis format:

```
s1 = tuple(value.split(" "))
s2 = zip(s1[1::2], s1[::2])
```

**For example:**

I have a entrance like: value = "**11.12345679** *12.987655* **11.3434454** *12.1223323*" and so on
The Python code above changes de entrance to:
s2 = "*12.987655* **11.12345679** *12.1223323*" and so on.

Changing the position of each coordinate pair, each entrance have thousands of coordinates.
To get the same effect with java (before java 8):
Using my knowledge of java (acquired before the java 8) I will need do that:

```
try {
    String result = "", right = "", left = "";
    String[] txt = str.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < txt.length; i += 2) {
        right = txt[i];
        left = txt[i + 1];
        result += "," + left + " " + right;
    }
    return result.substring(1);
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    return null;
}
```

I will execute the java code above thousands of times, my question is: Java 8 has some new way to do this code above more like Python ?

My motivation to ask that question is because I came across with this news about Java 8:

```
List<String> someList = new ArrayList<>();
// Add some elements
someList.add("Generic (1.5)");
someList.add("Functional (8)");

// Open a stream
someList.stream()
// Turn all texts in Upper Case
.map(String::toUpperCase)
// Loop all elemnst in Upper Case
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Updating:**

The solution of Jean-François Savard was perfect using Java 8 like I asked, thank you so much Jean-Francois Savard

```
String str = "11.12345679 12.987655 11.3434454 12.1223323 11.12345679 12.987655 11.3434454 12.1223323";
String[] strs = str.split(" "); 
str = IntStream.range(0, strs.length) .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0) .mapToObj(i -> strs[i + 1] + " " + strs[i]) .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
System.out.println(str);
>> 12.987655 11.12345679,12.1223323 11.3434454,12.987655 11.12345679,12.1223323 11.3434454
```

The solution shown by Vampire and Tukayi fit perfectly in my problem, thanks a lot guys

```
String str = "11.12345679 12.987655 11.3434454 12.1223323 11.12345679
12.987655 11.3434454 12.1223323";
str = str.replaceAll("([^\\s]+) ([^\\s]+)(?: |$)", ",$2 $1").substring(1);
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to show example input and output; besides  showing code and telling us: this is what should happen. And hint: ignoring array out of bounds; and just returning null looks like a bug. You know, your processing goes wrong (because you are doing something wrong, or unexpected input) ... and you just ignore that?!

Comment: Is `return = result.substring(1);` going to compile?

Comment: Is there any chance you could leverage [jython](http://www.jython.org/)? That's most certainly the fastest option - no conversion required.

Comment: In any case, you can use your non Java8 knowledge to write Java code. I'd recommend you start there, then try to apply streams and lambdas, if you can

Comment: Well, question was closed, so here you go as a comment : String[] strs = str.split(" ");
    IntStream.range(0, strs.length)
      .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
   .mapToObj(i -> strs[i + 1] + " " + strs[i])
   .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

Comment: Note that it is generally a bad idea to concatenate strings in a loop without using StringBuilder.

Comment: I'm not a fan of regular expression, but this works: `str.replaceAll("([^\\s]+) ([^\\s]+)(?: |$)", ",$2 $1").substring(1)`.

Comment: @Tunaki clever, but Im skeptical about the performance of this, perhaps why you said you were not a fan ?

Comment: @Tunaki as the code is run often is is not good performance to always compile the regex and besides that it produces wrong result according to OP code, especially if uneven number of elements in string. Better solution: Define `private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^ ]++) ([^ ]++)(?: |$)");` in your class that the pattern does not need to be compiled on each execution (the possessive quantifiers make it more efficient). Then use this: `if ((new StringTokenizer(str, " ").countTokens() % 2) == 1) { return null; } return pattern.matcher(str).replaceAll(",$2 $1").substring(1);`

Comment: Sure @Vampire, pre-compiling the pattern is always recommended. You can't fit everything in a comment :). Good point about the number of tokens being uneven, didn't think of it.

Comment: Then write two, OP seems not tooo familiar with Java and even Java familiar ppl often don't know Regexes in and out and think about pre-compiling regexes. ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vampire this is exactly I was need, and works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the following in your class to precompile a Regex pattern

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^ ]++) ([^ ]++)(?: |$)");
```

Then in your method use

```
if ((new StringTokenizer(str, " ").countTokens() % 2) == 1) {
    return null;
}
return pattern.matcher(str).replaceAll(",$2 $1").substring(1);
```

to get the same result as in your original code.

---

If you depend on using Streams why-o-ever, here a Streams solution

```
String[] strs = str.split(" ");
return IntStream.range(0, strs.length)
                .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
                .mapToObj(i -> strs[i + 1] + " " + strs[i])
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: I stopped coding in java when it was in version 1.2, after this, I am developing in many different languages, now all of my old java codes and components are deprecated, the Streams solution sounds to me like be more compatible in the future, I liked the Regex solution as well.
Because I’m working in systems that must to be functional for the next years I must use the improvements of all languages that I need to work.
More one time thanks a lot Vampire by help me.

Comment: I don't think the regex solution will become incompatible in the future. I more think the regex solution will be longer lasting and probably also more performant, but that is to be tested.

Answer (score -5):

Java 8 added (among other things) Lambdas, Streams and Functional interfaces.

You can use streams to simplify looping over objects. But the syntax like you see in Python isn't the same as in java like that.

Comment: This isn't helpful without an example